# Github api tag is not created

Tags: github

I tried to create a tag using [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/#create-a-tag-object). I made a POST request to `/repos/:owner/:repo/git/tags`, and I get this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

But unfortunately no tag was created. The new tag simply does not exist.
What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of tags -- annotated and lightweight, you can check the difference [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

As [Github API](https://docs.github.com/cn/rest/git/tags#create-a-tag-object) puts, `/repos/:owner/:repo/git/tags` only created an annotated tag object, and then you should manually create a refrence with the sha of this tag object by calling [create refrence api](https://docs.github.com/cn/rest/git/refs#create-a-reference):

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/refs \
  -d '{"ref":"refs/tags/tagName","sha":"the sha of tag object"}'
```

In another case, if you only want to add a lightweight tag to one commit, you should directly call create refrence api without the first step:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/git/refs \
  -d '{"ref":"refs/tags/tagName","sha":"the sha of the commit that you want to tag"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The tagging didn't work for me. It shows created, but nothing appears on github. However, I managed to achieve tagging by creating pre-release. Which is not ideal, but still better than nothing:

```
curl --location --request POST 
'https://<giturl>/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
--data-raw '{
"tag_name": "v0.0.1", 
"target_commitish": "master",
"name": "v0.0.1",
"body": "This is for Release v0.0.1 of the product",
"draft": false,
"prerelease": true}'
```